# Dynamic Programming for Matching Size (least difference)

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, pseudocode, recurrence

I found [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476908/finding-minimum-sum-of-absolute-differences-between-heights-of-n-boys-and-m) which seeks to use dynamic programming to minimize the absolute difference between height for n boys and m girls in a match.

If I understand it correctly we will be sorting the first j boys and k girls by height (ascending? or descending?) where j<=k. Why is j <=k?

I do not understand how I can use the recurrence mentioned in the link:

```
(j,k−1) and (j−1,k−1)
```

to find the optimal matching for the values (j,k), based on whether you pair up boy j with girl k or not.

I'm clearly misunderstanding some things here but my goal is to write pseudo code for this solution. Here are my steps:

```
1. Sort heights Array[Boys] and Array[Girls]
2. To pair Optimally for the least absolute difference in height, simply pair in order so Array[Pairs][1] = Array[Boys][1] + Array[Girls][1]
3. Return which boy was paired with which girl
```

Please help me to implement the solution proposed in the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the answer you provided, there is always a better matching available if there is a cross edge between two matchings, when the heights are sorted for all the boys and all the girls in ascending order.

So a Dynamic programming solution with complexity of `O(n*m)` is possible.

So we have a state represented by 2 indexes, lets call them `i` and `j`, where `i` refers for boys and `j` refers to the girls, then at each state `(i, j)` we can make a move to the state `(i, j+1)`, i.e. the current `ith` boy does not choose the current `jth` girl or the move can be made to the state `(i+1, j+1)`, i.e. the current `jth` girl is chosen by the current `ith` boy and we choose the minimum between these two choices at every level.

This can be easily implemented using a DP solution.

Reccurrence :

```
DP[i][j] = minimum(
                    DP[i+1][j+1] + abs(heightOfBoy[i] - heightofGirl[j]),
                    DP[i][j+1] 
               );
```

Below is the code in c++ for recursive DP Solution :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define INF 1e9

using namespace std;

int n, m, htB[100] = {10,10,12,13,16}, htG[100] = {6,7,9,10,11,12,17}, dp[100][100];

int solve(int idx1, int idx2){
    if(idx1 == n) return 0;
    if(idx2 == m) return INF;

    if(dp[idx1][idx2] != -1) return dp[idx1][idx2];

    int v1, v2;

    //include current
    v1 = solve(idx1 + 1, idx2 + 1) + abs(htB[idx1] - htG[idx2]);

    //do not include current
    v2 = solve(idx1, idx2 + 1);

    return dp[idx1][idx2] = min(v1, v2);
}


int main(){

    n = 5, m = 7;
    sort(htB, htB+n);sort(htG, htG+m);
    for(int i = 0;i < 100;i++) for(int j = 0;j < 100;j++) dp[i][j] = -1;
    cout << solve(0, 0) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`Output : 4`

Link to solution on Ideone : http://ideone.com/K5FZ9x

The DP table output of the above solution :

```
 4        4        4        1000000000      1000000000      1000000000       1000000000       
-1        3        3        3               1000000000      1000000000       1000000000       
-1       -1        3        3               3               1000000000       1000000000       
-1       -1       -1        2               2               2                1000000000       
-1       -1       -1       -1               1               1                1
```

The answer is stored in the `DP[0][0]` state.

Comment: The reccurrence that is mentioned in the link provided by the OP is the same reccurrence that i have written, just the `topological order of evaluation` is different.

Comment: Thank you! Any idea what the base case would look like in a drawn matrix and what places an entry depends upon? That will help visualizing.

Comment: I guess recursion could have been used alternatively.  why was dynamic programming a good solution here?

Comment: Recursive solultion would have been exponential in complexity, that would be very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn that problem into a bipartite graph where the edge between a girl and a boy is the absolute difference between their heights like so `abs(hG - hB)`. Then you can use the bipartite matching algorithm to solve for a minimal matching. See this for more info http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/

Comment: It looks to me like that algorithm solves the *unweighted* variant, whereas here we need to give the edges weights and minimise the total sum.  This can also be done, but TTBOMK not in O(n^2).

Comment: You're right. The link to implementation that I posted above does not take weights into account. This can be solved with the hungarian algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm but not in O(n^2)